# How will the Starshot swarm accelerate perfectly?

Tags: space-travel, radiation-pressure, solar-sails

I was reading about the Breakthrough Initiative [Starshot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakthrough_Starshot) and I a question came to mind.

From my understanding, the "mothership" will focus powerful lasers on each of the tiny ships, accelerating them out of the solar system.

My thinking is that other photon radiation-emitting objects will interfere with the microships' flight (like the sun). Even with a much more focused force coming from the lasers, won't the sun apply a force in a different direction, causing the ships to veer slightly off course? Even if it's negligible over solar system distances, over the course of ~4.5 light years this would create a huge difference. If the sun and other radiation-emitting bodies won't affect the flight path, why won't they?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bulk of the acceleration will be done in the short period where the lasers are trained on the sails. The intensity of the lasers (100 GW or so) is going to be many orders of magnitude larger than sunlight (about 1000 W/m$^2$) and starlight (about 32 million times weaker than sunlight). So the main velocity vector will be set by the lasers, although I can imagine a careful design taking a bit of solar influence into account (not just the light, but also the solar gravity of 0.0059 N/kg that actually will be slightly higher than the light pressure of the sail if is not lighter than about 0.5 g/m$^2$).

In space the starlight is essentially isotropic, so it will not have a major effect.

Once the probe is launched there is really no reason to retain the solar sail and it could be discarded from the probe chip, removing most of the light pressure issues.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't consider that they would drop the sail after the acceleration period was over. :)

Comment: I'm not sure how you would go about dropping it. It's just as likely to come back into the probe as be accelerated away from it.